# active directory - taking out the nonexpiry value on accounts provided in csv

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2

i have been triying to run a simple script to select and set as nonexpiry some accounts in my domain with this script:

Import-Csv "C:\temp\ne.csv" | ForEach-Object ($samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"){ Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADUser -PasswordNeverExpires:$false}

however, it seems like i always receive an error about the -Identity switch or the variable. i get a null value.

can anyone shed a light to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\ne.csv" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName | Set-ADUser -PasswordNeverExpires $false}
```